# Direction of turning

Tags: c, math, arduino

How can I find out which direct you have to turn to reach a new setpoint the shortest way?

I have a piece of Arduino code which controls a steppermotor. With an encoder I get the position of the steppermotor in a value 0..2048.

Now I have a setpoint 200, and I move to 200 this should be clockwise. Now I am at 200 and I want to go to point 2000, this should happen counter-clockwise because this is the shortest way.

How can I efficiently calculate which way I should turn?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
delta = (setpoint << 5) - (current_position << 5);
delta = delta >> 5;
```

This assumes all variables are signed 16 bit. Your stepper has a count that "rolls over" at 2048 which is similar but different from how a processor's math rolls over. By shifting left five bits, you line up the stepper rollover with the CPU rollover and everything just works. By shifting the result back, you get the number of counts you need to move the stepper - in a signed value, so positive is one way and negative the other way.

Comment: I like this solution, it's elegant and fast!

Answer (score 1):

Subtract the old setpoint from the new.

If the absolute value of that difference is greater than 1024, then you add or subtract multiples of 2048 such that the result is no larger in absolute value than 1024.

Having done this, if the result of the above computation is positive, then you move in a clockwise direction by that amount. If the result is negative, then you move counterclockwise by the absolute value of that amount.